# Excel Error 1004 - Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm trying to clean up my spreedsheet. There are many blank cells which are throwing off the count. I tried using this code but it's giving me a run-time error.

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Dim c As Range, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Range("A1:JS87")

    For Each c In MyRange
        If Len(c) = 0 Then c.ClearContents
    Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Try `For each c in MyRange.Cells`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error might be triggered because of finding a merged cell (or equivalent). I did some tests and IsEmpty seems to skip these situations. In any case, I am also including an error catching to be completely sure.

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Dim c As Range, MyRange As Range
    Set MyRange = Range("A1:JS87")

    For Each c In MyRange
        On Error Resume Next
        If (Not IsEmpty(c.Value)) Then
            If Len(c) = 0 Then c.ClearContents
        End If
    Next c
End Sub
```

Comment: +1. Merged cells are difficult to work with, and cause problems especially when iterating over cells in a range, like this.

Comment: Is there any way to run this faster? It's taking a really long time to process.

Comment: This is a really fast configuration. The only reason I can come up with to explain it being too slow is that the cath part (On Error Resume Next) is actually being used. Error catching is pretty time consuming. But I don't known what might be provoking the errors (comment the aforementioned line and see in which cell it crashes and see what is wrong with this cell). ClearContents shouldn't take too long but I guess that c.Value = "", would be still quicker.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps this:  changed c to cells instead of range and used cells collection on the range.

Realized you may need c.value as well.  Otherwise what property of the cell are you looking at?

```
Sub ClearAll()
    Dim c As cell, MyRange As Range

    Set MyRange = Range("A1:JS87")

    For Each c In MyRange.cells
        If Len(c.value) = 0 Then c.ClearContents
    Next c

End Sub
```

[MSFT Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa221353%28v=office.11%29.aspx)

Comment: `.Value` is the default property of a cell/range.  `c = c.Value` will return true.